# How to rename a column to today`s date?

Tags: r, dataframe, rename, dplyr

I would love to rename a column to today`s date:

I`ve tried the base function Sys.Date() & dplyr pkg in the following syntax:

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df1 %>% select(Column 1, Column 2) %>% rename(toString(Sys.Date())= 'Old Column Name')
```

Does not work. Any idea?

Comment: If you have just one column in `df1` then this should work: 
`df2 <- df1 %>% setNames(toString(Sys.Date()))`

Comment: I got more columns than just 1 that I select, to be more specific-->updated the Q

Comment: Just want to point out that putting dates in column names is a *bad thing* if you adhere to the "tidy data" paradigm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you insist on dplyr and pipes, then simply define:

```
daynamer=function(df, oldname){
     args=list(df, oldname)
     names(args)=c(".data",toString(Sys.Date()))
     do.call(rename_, args)}
```

Then you can do:

```
> df1 = data.frame(x=1:5, y=1:5)
> df1 %>% daynamer("x")
  2016-02-18 y
1          1 1
2          2 2
3          3 3
4          4 4
5          5 5
```

Answer (score 10):

In `base` R:

```
names(df1)[names(df1) == "Old Column Name"] <- as.character(Sys.Date())
```

Answer (score 7):

Using `rename_` from `dplyr`:

```
df %>% rename_(.dots = setNames("Old Column Name ", sprintf("`%s`", format(Sys.Date(), format = "%Y-%m-%d"))))
```

Or

```
# using the built-in 'iris' data:
rename_(iris, .dots = setNames('Species', Sys.Date()))
```